# Xcode recieving data from parse

Tags: xcode, parsing

Is there any way to receive data from my parse server thing. I have a column in my parse called lastmsg, and is their a way to "download" data from the column and use it in a string in Xcode?

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a `PFQuery`, you can find the corresponding doc [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-basic/iOS)

I strongly suggest you keep that link close, there is all the needed information there, and you can find anything in the left column (how to use PFObjects, Queries, and so on).

It should be pretty straightforward if you follow their lead. Ask a question if you need further help with a more precise matter.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm getting an error; **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)'**

Comment: Show me the code you're using to perform your query, edit your question with itso everyone can see it cleary

Comment: i agree with zil you should really read the parse doc. it's very well explain with example etc.